# Issue in Classifying data based on multiple feature set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, knn

I am trying to classify data based on some pre-specified labels, got 4 columns as shown below:

```
room_class                          room_cluster  room_inb   room_view

Standard single sea view            Standard      single     sea
Deluxe twin Single                  Deluxe        single     -
Suite Superior room ocean view      Suite           -        ocean
Superior Double twin                Superior      Double     -
Deluxe Double room sea view         Deluxe        Double     sea
```

Earlier I have worked on a learning model based on Knn classifier,with only one of the feature column, as shown below:

```
room_class                          room_cluster 

Standard single sea view            Standard    
Deluxe twin Single                  Deluxe        
Suite Superior room ocean view      Suite           
Superior Double twin                Superior      
Deluxe Double room sea view         Deluxe
```

Wherein I would first padd the string values onto numeric values, so **'room_class'** would be **'Y'** set and **'room_cluster'** would be **'X'** with the same structure and then run Knn over them.However now two more rows have been appended to the main data which I wanna make use of.How do I combine the three rows i.e **room_cluster , room_inb , room_view** into **X** while keeping **room_class** as **Y** and then train a model on them.

Example: After training the model should classify the input into the following output.

**Input**: Double Superior Suite with Ocean view

**Expected Output**:
    room_cluster : Superior
    room_inb     : Double
    room_view    : Ocean

**Edit**: this was the question I referred for the single feature set:
[Classification accuracy based on single Feature set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076069/classification-accuracy-based-on-single-feature-set/55088352?noredirect=1#comment96936079_55088352)

Comment: Which implementation of KNN are you using?

Comment: i imported KNeighborsClassifier from sklearn.neighbors which is the basic model I guess.

Comment: You can just do the same thing to the other columns and use all of them as your independent variables.

Comment: So do I need to train them thrice or combine them into a single array which would then be X?

Comment: You combine them into a single **2D** array.

Comment: could you provide a short snippet as answer?

Comment: That would depend on how you originally structured your workflow.

Comment: I have added an edit , pointing to another answer which I referred